# Convert and use DataTable in WPF DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

In normal WinForm application you can do that:

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable = dataGridRecords.DataSource;
```

but how to do that with the WPF datagrid?

```
dataTable = dataGridRecords.ItemsSource;
```

won't work either.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In WPF you don't do this

```
DataGrid.ItemsSource = DataTable;
```

Instead you do

```
 DataGrid.ItemsSource = DataTable.AsDataView();
```

In order to get DataTable back you can do something like this

```
public static DataTable DataViewAsDataTable(DataView dv)
{
    DataTable dt = dv.Table.Clone();
    foreach (DataRowView drv in dv)
       dt.ImportRow(drv.Row);
    return dt;
}

DataView view = (DataView) dataGrid.ItemsSource;
DataTable table = DataViewAsDataTable(view)
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need the `DataViewAsDataTable` method. Just do the following:

`DataTable dt = ((DataView)dataGrid1.ItemsSource).ToTable();`

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
    public static DataTable DataGridtoDataTable(DataGrid dg)
    {


        dg.SelectAllCells();
        dg.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridClipboardCopyMode.IncludeHeader;
        ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(null, dg);
        dg.UnselectAllCells();
        String result = (string)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue);
        string[] Lines = result.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        string[] Fields;
        Fields = Lines[0].Split(new char[] { ',' });
        int Cols = Fields.GetLength(0);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i < Cols; i++)
            dt.Columns.Add(Fields[i].ToUpper(), typeof(string));
        DataRow Row;
        for (int i = 1; i < Lines.GetLength(0)-1; i++)
        {
            Fields = Lines[i].Split(new char[] { ',' });
            Row = dt.NewRow();
            for (int f = 0; f < Cols; f++)
            {
                Row[f] = Fields[f];
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(Row);
        }
        return dt;

    }
```

Comment: If you have a comma anywhere in your data this will mess it up