# DataGrid the method DataSource not found

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datasource

I am trying to build a DataGrid - Not a DataGridView as it does not seem to be available on Visual Studio 2010.

I want to add rows dynamically (I think I can do that) but in order to display the result I need assign the data to the DataGrid, all the examples say I should use DataSource but Visual Studio insists that this is not available. To code I have found else where is like this.

```
private void BindToDataView(System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid myGrid)
{
    // Create a DataView using the DataTable.
    DataTable myTable = new DataTable("Suppliers");
    // Insert code to create and populate columns.
    DataView myDataView = new DataView(myTable);
    myGrid.DataSource = myDataView;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You post code that works (elsewhere) and then want us to answer what's wrong in the code that you didn't post?

Comment: The code does not compile on Visual Studio 2010 that I am using. I t gives an error saying DataGrid does not contain definition DataSource.

Comment: Start by specifying the GUI : WinForms., WPF or ASP.NET?

Comment: But the body of your code appears to target WinForms. DataGrid has an ItemsSsource property.

Answer (score 5):

You pass in a WPF DataGrid ([`System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx)) and use code meant for a WinForms DataGrid ([`System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid.aspx)).

WPF DataGrids use [`ItemsSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx).
WinForms DataGrids use [`DataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid.datasource.aspx).

Comment: There is a explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984686/convert-and-use-datatable-in-wpf-datagrid that helped resolve the issue.