# DataTable as DataGrid.ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, datatable

hi i want to bind a `DataTable` with multiple columns to an `DataGrid` in codebehind

```
    var dt = new DataTable();

    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("1"));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("2"));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("3"));

    dt.Rows.Add(ff.Mo);
    dt.Rows.Add(ff.Di);
    dt.Rows.Add(ff.Mi);
    dt.Rows.Add(ff.Do);
    dt.Rows.Add(ff.Fr);
    dt.Rows.Add(ff.Sa);
    dt.Rows.Add(ff.So);
// ff is a object that contains List<myCellObj>

DataGrid DGrid = new DataGrid();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
   DataGridTemplateColumn templateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
   templateColumn.HeaderTemplate = HeaderDt;
   templateColumn.CellTemplate = ItemDt; //specified DataTemplate for myCellObj

   DGrid.Columns.Add(templateColumn);
}
```

now how do i set my `dt` as `ItemsSource`, `Datacontext` or what ever to get it in to my `View`
also if you could provide me a way to bind directly to my `Object ff`

anything that could help is greatly appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984686/convert-and-use-datatable-in-wpf-datagrid

Comment: @AbZy yes i tried it and yes it didn't work

Comment: @moncadad exactly what i was looking for looks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Assuming you're in WPF simply say:

```
DGrid.ItemsSource = dt.AsDataView();
```

No need to manually setup your columns on your DataGrid, assigning the DataTable will set these up for you.

Comment: It gives me an error : Two-way binding requires Path or XPath.

Comment: If one doesn't add column by column, then formatting of DataGrid doesn't applies only data is shown. Please help with dynamically formatting the columns, like changin colors.

Comment: I would suggest asking a new question then. This question is not related to formatting the datagrid, only setting the data source.