# Winforms code for datatable - what's the WPF equivalent?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I have the following code in a Winforms application, which works as expected:

```
private void btnFetchCollections_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var scDal = new SiteCollectionDal();
        var dt = new DataTable();

        List<SiteCollectionEntity> siteCollections = scDal.FetchSiteCollections();

        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Site Name", typeof(string)));

        foreach (SiteCollectionEntity siteCollectionEntity in siteCollections)
        {
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();

            row["Site Name"] = siteCollectionEntity.Url;

            dt.Rows.Add(row);

            dt.AcceptChanges();
        }

        dataSiteCollections.DataSource = dt;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

I'm now building a new WPF interface for this project, and the following doesn't work - how should I be approaching this?

```
private void btnFetchSiteCollections_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var scDal = new SiteCollectionDal();
        var dt = new DataTable();

        List<SiteCollectionEntity> siteCollections = scDal.FetchSiteCollections();

        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Site Name", typeof(string)));

        foreach (SiteCollectionEntity siteCollectionEntity in siteCollections)
        {
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();

            row["Site Name"] = siteCollectionEntity.Url;

            dt.Rows.Add(row);

            dt.AcceptChanges();
        }

        dataSiteCollections.ItemsSource = dt;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

The error I'm receiving is on the following line:

```
dataSiteCollections.ItemsSource = dt;
```

Which is:

> Cannot convert source type 'System.Data.DataTable' to target type
>   'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Comment: Try inserting a `.ToList();` like this: `dataSiteCollections.ItemsSource = dt.ToList();`

Comment: @Tico That just gives  the error 'Cannot resolve symbol 'ToList'

Comment: possible duplicate of [DataTable as DataGrid.ItemsSource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942105/datatable-as-datagrid-itemssource)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
dataSiteCollections.ItemsSource = dt.AsDataView();
```