# datagrid in WPF is empty when populating it from database

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

The problem is when ever i populate the datagrid  it shows me the number of rows available in database but the data in the rows is empty in datagrid. here is a snippet:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {                
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
                command.CommandText = "select item_name from prod_info";
                cmdd.Connection = connection;
                Datatable table= new Datatable();
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                adapter.Fill(table);
                dataGrid1.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

this is the xaml code here:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="308" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="59,89,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="502" ItemsSource="{Binding }"/>
```

Comment: what is table exactly, a DataSet?

Comment: @Juan its a Datatable...
i am the correction...check it out now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: AutoGenerateColumns = "True"

Then maybe it's also necessary:

```
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = table.AsDataView();
```

as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942105/datatable-as-datagrid-itemssource)

Comment: AutoGenerateColumns = "True"

Comment: Glad to help, I updated the answer if u could please mark it as answer