# How do you create a Datatable in wpf?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datatable, dataset

I'm writing an application in c# using wpf and i was wondering how do you create a data table in wpf? This is a really dumb question, i'm aware, but it doesn't appear like i'm using the correct references as the data table object never appears when i try to create it. My references are as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data.Sql;
```

Comment: Don't use `System.Data.DataTable` in WPF. It is a really poor way to store your data. Create a proper Data Model instead.

Comment: @HighCore Could you develop a little why this is convenient in Windows Forms, but not in WPF? Or is this a statement also appliable outside of WPF?

Comment: For an answer, see the question following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984686/convert-and-use-datatable-in-wpf-datagrid

Comment: @Dereckson winforms is a crappy UI framework, and works well with crappy data structures (such as magic-string based, untyped `DataTable` stuff where everything is `object` and constantly needs `.ToString()`, `.Parse()` or casting type of stuff). horrible winforms code goes hand-to-hand with horrible `DataTable` based code. Beautiful XAML should be accompanied with proper data structures to achieve maximum code quality

Comment: @Dereckson BTW, WPF facing ViewModels and application code should be as much "cross-platform" and "framework independent" as possible, and `System.Data` does not exist, for example, in WinRT. Therefore any `DataTable` based code cannot be ported to WinRT.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a method that creates a DataTable...

```
    private void CreateDataTable()
    {
        System.Data.DataTable dt = new DataTable("MyTable");
        dt.Columns.Add("MyColumn", typeof (string));
        dt.Rows.Add("row of data");
    }
```

The relevant assembly (as identified by HighCore in the commentary) is System.Data.  If it is not included in your references, you can add it via the 'add reference' context menu.

Comment: The issue is the fact that my listed reference contained the word windows. (System.Data as opposed to Stystem.Windows.Data) thanks for the help!