# Fill MYSQL database with datagrid information in C# wpf

Tags: c#, mysql, datatable, wpfdatagrid, itemssource

Believe me I have googled it. Its become clear that the C# code used on win-forms doesn't work on C# WPF for semi-obvious reasons. What's not obvious though is how to Fill a MYSQL table with modified or completely new data from a data grid. It works fine the other way around though (filling the datagrid with MYSQL data).

```
    private void Save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string sqlcon = "datasource = localhost; port = 3306; username = root; password = Avalisque";
        string queryadd = "insert into users.login (user_name,pass_word,gender,first_name,second_name,third_name,surname,security_question,answer);";
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(sqlcon);
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(queryadd, con);
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();


        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable("login");
            da.Fill(ds);
            DG.datasource = ds.Tables[0];
            da.Update(dt);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }


    }
```

(DG being the datagrid).
and this is the error message:

*'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid' does not contain a definition for 'datasource' and no extension method 'datasource' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

Any form of help much appreciated. Kinda desperate here. Please and thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for `DG.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable();`

You are getting that error because the [`System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx) doesn't have a property named `datasource`.

[DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx) shows you how to make a DataTable into an Enumarable where T : DataRow

Comment: yeah when i do that i get this message:- 

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataTable' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)  -: ds.Tables[0]; is underlined...

Comment: @Tim I updated my answer to make the DataTable Enumerable.  I think that should work.  Let me know if there is still an issue.

Comment: thanks for that. Been playing around with it but no luck so far :/              Cannot convert method group 'AsEnumerable' to non-delegate type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. Did you intend to invoke the method?    thats the error message. sigh#

Comment: @Tim Added parenthesis to make it a method call.  Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @Tim Did this help you out.  If so please +1 and/or mark it as the answer.  If not please let me know what else I can do to help.

Comment: this code required me do do quite a bit of heavy editing to the code and query, lots of rearranging needed and needed me to link declaration of "dt" from initialization too but it did its job. You'd think there'd be a more straight forward way to handle stuff like this. Much gratitude Harrison.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a property ItemsSource.

Also do not forget that wpf works well with the mvvm pattern. In fact your itemsource probably should be an ObservableCollection available in your viewModel.

Comment: "ObservableCollection" been googling that. Seems like it would work very easily on implementation but from what i gather it seems like comunication only goes one way, like into the MMYSQL database. Am i missing something? Please give me a hint.

Comment: Ok tim, I have suggested an observableCollection with the mvvm because I think it's a good way to do this, but it's long to explain. google mvvm wpf. otherwise, you can find a way with your datatable here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984686/convert-and-use-datatable-in-wpf-datagrid